# How to set PHP not to check undefind index for $_GET when E_NOTICE is on?

Tags: php

When E_NOTICE is set to on, PHP will report undefined index for arrays. I want to suppress this error for `$_GET` only. Is there any way to do that other than prepend every `$_GET[]` with `@`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is to check for the existence of the array key before you use it each time, using `isset`.

So instead of

```
$cow=(int)$_GET['cow'];
```

do

```
if(isset($_GET['cow'])){ $cow=(int)$_GET['cow']; }
```

That's verbose, however. So, you can wrap this in a function such as

```
function get($key_name){
  return isset($_GET[$key_name])?$_GET[$key_name]:null;
  }
```

and then,

```
$cow=get('cow');
```

Comment: Also it is handy to add second argument with `$default` to return if variable doesn't exist in `$_GET`.

Comment: @zerkms indeed, I use a function such as that too, called get_or_else like in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is to use something like isset or [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) first, thus making sure your code successfully handles things when the array index is outright missing, as opposed to `''` or zero:

```
$foo = array_key_exists('foo', $_GET) ? $_GET['foo'] : 'Whoops!';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify all the $_GET references in your code, you could create your own error handler to PHP, by using `set_error_handler` function

Example (completely untested, but shows the idea):

```
function myErrHandler ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if(strstr("GET", $errstr)) {
        // suppress message
        return true;
    }

    // otherwise, continue with PHP internal error handler
    return false;
}

set_error_handler("myErrHandler", E_NOTICE);
```